# SD Storage - Apps move back to internal Storage after update

Tags: adoptable-storage

I have a query pertaining to the moving of Apps across the various storage drives in android. I recently purchased a **VFD 700** , running on **Android 6.0**. This has 16 GB Internal storage, along with which I have added a 128 GB SD Card for additional storage. 
I have formatted the SD card as Internal storage to facilitate movement of the applications from the main storage to the secondary storage which is my SD  card and this works fine sans issues. 
However when the apps get updated, the apps move back to the internal storage , depleting  the storage and forcing me again have to move them to the SD card. This is how android works or is this a bug in the Android v6.0.
Please suggest any settings change or app which can manage this , i.e. retaining the Apps  in their installed location, without having to manually move them across every time an update is done.

Cheers,

Ashoka

Comment: Did you migrated data to adopted storage? If yes, than apps probably move to internal storage because of poor design.

Comment: hi @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје , I did. I used the Apps2SD app to move the app to the SD card. They work fine all data got migrated to the storage, but say  when the app publisher releases an update, I take the update of the app, then the app moves back to the main storage. It is strange and I've got to move them again.

Comment: Does that happens with all apps or just some of them?

Comment: Most of the apps , as far as I can remember

Comment: Oh.. Btw, did you used marshmallow's feature to format sd card as adoptable storage? If you did than you don't need aditional apps you could move apps from app manager?